# Adjust image saturation by color type

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have the following method, which takes an array of pixel data, and then adjusts the saturation to `this.adjustmentAmount` currently it works! But I want to take it further by only adjusting the saturation of these colors:
`red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta`

How can this be done?

```
public int[] filter(String keep){
    for(int i = 0; i < this.pixels.length; i++){
        int pixel = this.pixels[i];
        int red = Colors.red(pixel);
        int green = Colors.green(pixel);
        int blue = Colors.blue(pixel);

        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.RGBtoHSB(red, green, blue, hsv);
        hsv[1] += (float)(this.adjustmentAmount * 0.01);
        if(hsv[1] > 1){
            hsv[1] = 1;
        }else if(hsv[1] < 0){
            hsv[1] = 0;
        }

        int newpixel = Color.HSBtoRGB(hsv[0], hsv[1], hsv[2]);



        red = Colors.red(newpixel);
        green = Colors.green(newpixel);
        blue = Colors.blue(newpixel);

        this.pixels[i] = Colors.rgba(red, green, blue);
    }
    return this.pixels;
}
```

Here is a working sscce (**Just modify the file name**):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sscce;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Ryan
 */
public class Sscce extends JFrame{

    public Layer layer;

    public Sscce(){
    try{
            this.setSize(800, 600);
            this.setResizable(false);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            layer = new Layer();
            layer.setImage("http://www.prikol.ru/wp-content/gallery/october-2012/datacenter-01.jpg");
            this.add(layer);
            this.revalidate();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    applySat();
                }
            }, 500);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Sscce.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    protected void applySat(){
        Saturation sat = new Saturation();
        sat.setAmount(-100);
        BufferedImage img = this.layer.getImage();
        int[] pixels = new int[img.getWidth() * img.getHeight()];
        this.layer.getImage().getRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), pixels, 0, img.getWidth());
        sat.setPixels(pixels);
        pixels = sat.filter("yellow");
        img.setRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), pixels, 0, img.getWidth());
        this.layer.setImage(img);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Sscce();
    }
}


class Layer extends JPanel{

    protected BufferedImage image;

    public BufferedImage getImage(){
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image){
        this.image = image;
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void setImage(String filename) throws IOException{
        this.image = ImageIO.read(new URL(filename));
        this.setSize(this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight());
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight(), Color.black, null);
    }
}



class Saturation{

    protected volatile int[] pixels;
    protected int adjustmentAmount = 0;

    public void setPixels(int[] pixels){
        this.pixels = pixels;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount){
        this.adjustmentAmount = amount;
    }

    public int[] filter(String keep){
        for(int i = 0; i < this.pixels.length; i++){
            int pixel = this.pixels[i];
            int red = Colors.red(pixel);
            int green = Colors.green(pixel);
            int blue = Colors.blue(pixel);

            float[] hsv = new float[3];
            Color.RGBtoHSB(red, green, blue, hsv);
            hsv[1] += (float)(this.adjustmentAmount * 0.01);
            if(hsv[1] > 1){
                hsv[1] = 1;
            }else if(hsv[1] < 0){
                hsv[1] = 0;
            }

            int newpixel = Color.HSBtoRGB(hsv[0], hsv[1], hsv[2]);
            red = Colors.red(newpixel);
            green = Colors.green(newpixel);
            blue = Colors.blue(newpixel);

            this.pixels[i] = Colors.rgba(red, green, blue);
        }
        return this.pixels;
    }
}


class Colors{

    public static int rgba(int red, int green, int blue, Integer alpha){
        int rgba = alpha;
        rgba = (rgba << 8) + red;
        rgba = (rgba << 8) + green;
        rgba = (rgba << 8) + blue;
        return rgba;
    }

    public static int rgba(int red, int green, int blue){
        int rgba = 255;
        rgba = (rgba << 8) + red;
        rgba = (rgba << 8) + green;
        rgba = (rgba << 8) + blue;
        return rgba;
    }
    public static int[] getrgba(int color){
        int[] colors = new int[3];
        colors[0] = Colors.red(color);
        colors[1] = Colors.green(color);
        colors[2] = Colors.blue(color);
        return colors;
    }

    public static int alpha(int color){
        return color >> 24 & 0x0FF;
    }

    public static int red(int color){
        return color >> 16 & 0x0FF;
    }

    public static int green(int color){
        return color >> 8 & 0x0FF;
    }

    public static int blue(int color){
        return color & 0x0FF;
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okay I added an SSCCE

Comment: `layer.setImage("C:\\Users\\Ryan\\Desktop\\google-server-room5.jpg");`  Hot-link to an image or generate it in code, unless you expect me to come to your house to view this.

Comment: @AndrewThompson There it now loads from a url

Comment: Can you make the code break with [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AuY9o.png?s=128&g=1)?  I ask because it is just 7.07 KB - as opposed to that other image which is 1/4 meg (it never occurred to you to link to a ***small*** image?!?).

Comment: Is this too big for you? http://news.images.itv.com/image/file/106895/image_update_423f0f108dedb0c0_1350585197_9j-4aaqsk.jpeg

Comment: How many KB is it?  And why don't you answer **my** question about the 7.07 KB image?

Comment: Yes the 7k one works, but it doesn't have enough colors to work with. Mine is 234 kb.

Comment: *"Mine is 234 kb."*  If you want my help, do better.  Do an image search on Google for small width x height images (that is a good starting point for 'small in bytes').  Check they are under ..40Kb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set threshold values on RGB channels for the color you have mentioned.

For example default YELLOW color is defined as

```
RED: 255
GREEN : 255
BLUE : 0
```

But you probably want to accept little darker ones as yellow. Then you should set range on above three channel for YELLOW as below:

```
RED : [240 - 255]
GREEN : [240 - 255]
BLUE : [0 - 30]
```

You can apply this method for all colors and decide to adjust the saturation or not.

Comment: Here is how I catch yellow: `if(red >= 50 && green >= 50 && blue <= 100){` then I remove it by setting the saturation to `0`

Comment: I think ranges you said doesn't belong to yellow as you can see on http://www.colorpicker.com/
It seems like dark blue.

Comment: Odd, in my test picture, it doesn't touch the blues